# Javafx maximize/minimize ruins my layout

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am working on a javafx game and the layout is just how i want it to be. 
However the layout is only applied after i resize my window because of my width and height bindings. When the app starts or when it is minimized or maximized the layout gets messed up.

After the layout gets messed up just resizing it a little brings it back to normal.

I have tried to listen to the maximize and minimize events and use the same updating methods that i used when resizing but it did not work.

```
        primaryStage.maximizedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
            gamePane.updatePlayerPanes();
        }
    });
```

I am truly lost. I have tried a lot of things but non worked the layout keeps getting messed up when minimized or maximized.

Just started:
https://prnt.sc/jf2akp

After resizing a tiny bit:
http://prntscr.com/jf2b19

I am mainly using a GridPane and using a StackPane for the middle pane.

Any ideas are appreciated thanks.

Edit:

This is a simple class that simulates the problem

Just started: http://prntscr.com/jfb4lm

After resizing a tiny bit: http://prntscr.com/jfb4ud

```
   package test;
   import javafx.application.Application;
   import javafx.geometry.HPos;
   import javafx.geometry.VPos;
   import javafx.scene.Scene;
   import javafx.scene.image.Image;
   import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
   import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
   import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
   import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
   import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
   import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
   import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
   import javafx.stage.Stage;
   public class Test extends Application
   {
       @Override
       public void start(Stage primaryStage)
       {
           BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
           GridPane gp = new GridPane();
           gp.prefHeight(500);
           gp.prefWidth(500);
           for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
               gp.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(50, 50, Double.MAX_VALUE, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
           }
           for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
               gp.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(50, 50, Double.MAX_VALUE, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
           }
           bp.setCenter(gp);
           //Simulate the center pane
           StackPane centerPane = new StackPane();
           centerPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Green");
           //Add a bunch of cards
           for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
           {
               Image img = new Image("file:AS_.png");
               ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
               imgView.setPreserveRatio(true);
                      imgView.fitHeightProperty().bind(centerPane.heightProperty().divide(2));
               imgView.setRotate(Math.random()*180);
               centerPane.getChildren().add(imgView);
           }
           gp.add(centerPane, 1, 1, 3, 3);
           Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 300, 300);
           primaryStage.setScene(scene);
           primaryStage.show();
       }
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           launch(args);
       }
   }
```

Is there any way to force a resize or something?

Comment: can you post the code about your gridpane and stackpane

Comment: Its pretty long 500 lines, anything specific that you are looking for? certain methods or listeners ?

Comment: can you prepare a simple and verifiable code using simple (base) components that produces your same problem (and same layout of course)

Comment: Done! You can find the simple test code in the edit. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Interesting after removing the bind used in the image view everything was fine. I need to bind my image height though is there another way to do it?

Comment: I am  experiencing the same problem. Resizing works fine. Maximizing doesn't - or better: only in parts. I guess it has something to do with the timing when certain events are thrown and when real  layout occurs.

Answer (score 0):

by adding these two lines after `primaryStage.show();`, the problem seems to be solved. hope it helps in your real application

```
GridPane.setFillHeight(centerPane, true);
GridPane.setFillWidth(centerPane, true);
```

your test class:

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        gp.prefHeight(500);
        gp.prefWidth(500);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            gp.getColumnConstraints()
                    .add(new ColumnConstraints(50, 50, Double.MAX_VALUE, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            gp.getRowConstraints()
                    .add(new RowConstraints(50, 50, Double.MAX_VALUE, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
        }
        bp.setCenter(gp);
        // Simulate the center pane
        StackPane centerPane = new StackPane();
        centerPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Green");
        // Add a bunch of cards
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Image img = new Image("file:AS_.png");
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
            imgView.setPreserveRatio(true);
            imgView.fitHeightProperty().bind(centerPane.heightProperty().divide(2));
            imgView.setRotate(Math.random() * 180);
            centerPane.getChildren().add(imgView);
        }
        gp.add(centerPane, 1, 1, 3, 3);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        GridPane.setFillHeight(centerPane, true);
        GridPane.setFillWidth(centerPane, true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. It does help a little with the start, the elements are still not quite in their place but they are closer somehow. But the maximizing and minimizing are still the same. Isn't there a way to force fire a resize event  or to recalculate the positions or redraw the scene or something ?